# Esper error: ERROR com.espertech.esper.timer.EPLTimerTask - Timer thread caught unhandled exception: null

Tags: java, esper

I receive this error in Esper. What is the cause?

```
[com.espertech.esper.Timer-EsperService-0] ERROR com.espertech.esper.timer.EPLTimerTask  - Timer thread caught unhandled exception: null
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
            at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap.tooHigh(TreeMap.java:1394)
            at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap.absLowest(TreeMap.java:1425)
            at java.util.TreeMap$AscendingSubMap$AscendingEntrySetView.iterator(TreeMap.java:1908)
            at java.util.AbstractMap$2$1.<init>(AbstractMap.java:389)
            at java.util.AbstractMap$2.iterator(AbstractMap.java:388)
            at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterParamIndexCompare.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexCompare.java:161)
            at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterParamIndexCompare.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexCompare.java:171)
            at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterHandleSetNode.matchEvent(FilterHandleSetNode.java:99)
            at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchType(EventTypeIndex.java:170)
            at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchEvent(EventTypeIndex.java:108)
            at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceBase.retryableMatchEvent(FilterServiceBase.java:170)
```

Comment: The stack in you post is incomplete. I suggest you post the complete stack and also post the code that is causing this.

Comment: The complete stack would not help - it's about 30 pages long, and most of it's the same. There is no recursion involved, it's just that Esper does a lot of work and uses a lot of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the exception mentions "StackOverflowError".

The [default stack size for 64-bit Java is 1 megabyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020619/where-to-find-default-xss-value-for-sun-oracle-jvm).

Increase to 2 megabytes using JVM option `-Xss2m`.

Exercise caution: increasing the stack size increases per-thread RAM usage.