# ERROR XJ001: Java exception: ': java.lang.StackOverflowError'

Tags: java, sql, database, derby, javadb

I am using Derby DB and I am executing simple INSERT statement, well there is around 9000 of rows to be filled in. During that I get the error:

ERROR XJ001: Java exception: ': java.lang.StackOverflowError'

Can anyone help me with some tips please?

Thanks

Remi

Comment: Show your query to see what are you trying

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I find three different ways to solve it:

- Use an `INSERT` command per row.
- Split the rows in several `INSERT` commands with multiple (but less) rows in `VALUES` clause.
- Use the [-Xss](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) option to set the thread stack size of the Java Virtual Machine. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643977/4071001) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030999/4071001) for better understanding about  this option.