# How to save and load a large Graph structure with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, graph, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to persist and load the following simple structure (resembling a directed graph) using **JPA 2.1**, **Hibernate 4.3.7** and **Spring Data**:

**Graph.java**

```
@Entity
public class Graph extends PersistableObject {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "graph")
    private Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();

    // getters, setters...
}
```

**Node.java**

```
@Entity
public class Node extends PersistableObject {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Set<Node> neighbors = new HashSet<Node>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Graph graph;

    // getters, setters...
}
```

## The Problem

In most cases, the lazy loading behaviour is fine. The problem is that, on some occasions in my application, I need to fully load a given graph (including all lazy references) and also persist a full graph in an **efficient** way, **without** performing **N+1 SQL queries**. Also, when **storing** a new graph, I get a `StackOverflowError` as soon as the graph becomes too big (> 1000 nodes).

## Questions

1. How can I store a new graph in the database with 10.000+ nodes, given that Hibernate seems to choke on a graph with 1000 nodes with a `StackOverflowError` already? Any useful tricks?
2. How can I fully load a graph and resolve all lazy references without performing N+1 SQL queries?

## What I tried so far

I have no clue how to solve problem 1). As for problem 2), I tried to use the following HQL query:

I'm currently trying to do it using HQL with fetch joins:

```
FROM Graph g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.nodes node LEFT JOIN FETCH node.neighbors WHERE g.id = ?1
```

... where ?1 refers to a string parameter containing the graph id. However, this seems to result in one SQL SELECT per node stored in the graph, which leads to horrible performance on graphs with several thousands of nodes. Using Hibernate's **FetchProfiles** produced the same result.

## Important -EDIT-

**EDIT 1:** It turns out that **Spring Data JpaRepositories** perform their `save(T)` operation by first calling `entityManager.merge(...)`, then calling `entityManager.persist(...`). The `StackOverflowError` does **not** occur on a "raw" `entityManager.persist(...)`, but it **does** occur in `entityManager.merge(...)`. It still doesn't solve the issue though, why does this happen on a merge?

**EDIT 2:** I think that this is really a bug in Hibernate. I've filed a bug report with a complete, self-contained JUnit test project. In case somebody is interested, you can find it here:
[Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9565)

## Supplementary Material

Here's the `PersistableObject` class which uses a UUID for it's `@ID`, and an eclipse-generated `hashCode()` and `equals(...)` method based on that ID.

**PersistableObject.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistableObject {

    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    // hashCode() and equals() auto-generated by eclipse based on this.id

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (this.id == null ? 0 : this.id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        PersistableObject other = (PersistableObject) obj;
        if (this.id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // getters, setters...

}
```

If you want to try it for yourself, here's a factory that generates a random graph:

**GraphFactory.java**

```
public class GraphFactory {

    public static Graph createRandomGraph(final int numberOfNodes, final int edgesPerNode) {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        // we use this list for random index access
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < numberOfNodes; nodeIndex++) {
            Node node = new Node();
            node.setGraph(graph);
            graph.getNodes().add(node);
            nodes.add(node);
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            for (int edgeIndex = 0; edgeIndex < edgesPerNode; edgeIndex++) {
                int randomTargetNodeIndex = random.nextInt(nodes.size());
                Node targetNode = nodes.get(randomTargetNodeIndex);
                node.getNeighbors().add(targetNode);
            }
        }
        return graph;
    }
}
```

**The Stack Trace**

The stack trace of the `StackOverflowError` repeatedly contains the following sequence (directly one after the other):

```
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:886) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:868) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
```

Comment: The back-reference from `Node` to `Graph` doesn't make sense for me. And it's probably the reason for the your problem.

Comment: @zeroflagL Thanks for your response. The back reference from Node to Graph is simply the inverse reference of `graph.nodes`. It exists for two reasons:

 1. In a scenario where only the Graph is loaded lazily, it allows you to insert nodes into a graph (by setting `newNode.graph`) without ever having to load the whole collection of nodes in a graph. On the database side, it turns into a convenient foreign key column.

 2. It allows you to prevent a node from showing up in two graphs.

I think I actually found a bug in Hibernate:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9565

Answer (score 11):

During the last 24 hours I did a lot of web research on this topic and I'll try to give a tentative answer here. Please do correct me if I'm wrong on something.

### Problem: Hibernate StackOverflowException on entityManager.merge(...)

This seems to be a general issue with ORM. By nature, the "merge" algorithm is recursive. If there is a path (from entity to entity) in your model that has too many entities in it, without ever referencing a known entity in between, the recursion depth of the algorithm is larger than the stack size of your JVM.

#### Solution 1: Increase the stack size of your JVM

If you know that your model is just slightly too large for the stack size of your JVM, you can increase that value by using the start parameter **-Xss** (and a suitable value) to increase it. However, note that this value is static, so if you load a larger model than before, you would have to increase it again.

#### Solution 2: Breaking up the entity chains

This is definitly not a solution in the spirit of Object-Relational Mapping, but to my current knowledge, it is the only solution that effectively scales well with growing model size. The idea is that you replace a normal Java reference in your `@Entity` classes with a primitive value that contains the `@Id` value of the target entity instead. So if your target `@Entity` uses an id value of type `long`, you would have to store a `long` value. It is then up to the application layer to resolve the reference as needed (by performing a `findById(...)` query on the database).

Applied to the graph scenario from the question post, we would have to change the `Node` class to this:

```
@Entity
public class Node extends PersistableObject {

    // note this new mapping!
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> neighbors = new HashSet<String>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Graph graph;

    // getters, setters...

}
```

### Problem: N+1 SQL selects

I was actually fooled by Spring and Hibernate here. My Unit test used a `JpaRepository` and called  `repository.save(graph)` followed by `repository.fullyLoadById(graphId)` (which had an `@Query` annotation using the HQL fetch join query from the question post) and measured the time for each operation. The SQL select queries that popped up in my console log did **not** come from the `fullyLoadById` query, but from `repository.save(graph)`. What spring repositories do here is to first call `entityManager.merge(...)` on the object that we want to save. Merge, in turn, fetches the current state of the entity from the database. This fetching results in the large number of SQL select statements that I experienced. My load query actually was performed in a single SQL query, as intended.

#### Solution:

If you have a fairly large object graph and you know that it is definitly new, not contained in the database, and does not reference any entity that is stored in the database, you can skip the `merge(...)` step and directly call `entityManager.persist(...)` on it for better performance. Spring repositories always use `merge(...)` for safety reasons. `persist(...)` will attempt an SQL `INSERT` statement, which will **fail** if there is already a row with the given ID in the database.

Also, note that Hibernate will always log all queries one by one if you use `hibernate.show_sql = true`. JDBC batching takes place after the queries have been generated. So if you see lots of queries in your log, it does not necessarily mean that you had as many DB roundtrips.

Comment: Do you know if there is something to configure JPA-Hibernate to save in a Breadth-first instead of depth-first?

Comment: As far as I know, in Hibernate the process is always depth-first. What is even more embarassing is that it is implemented with recursive method calls (instead of using a stack), which means that a list of 1000 linked entities will likely cause a Java call stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as you did a few years back and couldn't find anything except your post and answer, thank you.

Now, I would like to add a few things to your answer, hope will be helpful for someone.

### Increase the stack size of your JVM

Setting **-Xss** should work for most of the use-cases, however, it's not the solution in this case. [Each thread has at least one stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030120/what-is-the-default-stack-size-can-it-grow-how-does-it-work-with-garbage-colle), some of them have more (e.i. depending on JVM you use, there could be JVM OS thread size and JVM native thread size).

Running a quick check (using VisualVM) I discovered, that my WildFly application uses more than 150 threads(!). [Assuming, that the thread size is 1M](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/openj9/xss/index.html) (depending on your VM and probably many other factors), and increasing it to 4 (-Xss4M) [could potentially quadruple all stacks](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kKgG/impact-of-stack-sizes-on-the-system?language=en_US), which will result in using not 150M, but 600M used memory, quite a waste.

### Not using CASCADE

Using Hibernate 5.3.20 I tested very similar example to yours and found out that removing cascade from

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
private Set<Node> neighbors = new HashSet<Node>();
```

To

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Node> neighbours = new HashSet<Node>();
```

But you would have to manually merge, persist, etc., every node, same as in your second solution, but this time keeping the ‘hard’ link.
For anyone who wants to check it out, I created a [GitHub example](https://github.com/szymonk92/graphHibernate/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java), based on Hibernate Test Case Template.

After a quick run, you can find that `persistGraph()` test, that uses CASCASE, will fail after a few seconds. In order see it on green, increase stack -Xss6M.

Second test, `persistGraphNoCascade()`, uses no CASCADE for nextNode (neighbour in your case), no need to increase a stack size, and test runs a few times faster for me.