# Lightweight threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any JSR or other serious initiative to create lightweight threads in Java? Something similar to Golang's goroutines or Erlang processes.

Java threads are known for their heavy weight. Something like 512-1024 kb per thread is used so this limits the maximum number of threads. Context switching between java threads also takes a "long" time.

I've heard of Quasar "fibers" (http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) which are lightweight threads implemented as a lib. They seem a bit tricky to use though and haven't caught a lot of interest.

Ideally lightweight threads should be built into the core of the JVM.

Comment: Would you consider the master - worker pattern where threads are re-used? Perhaps a distrubuted version like Map Reduce or Hazelcast?

Comment: I'm thinking of a single web server being able to process 100 000 simultaneous clients and keeping one (lightweight) thread per request and making synchronous calls to external systems for each client.

Comment: Shouldn't you allow the web server to handle that? In any case 100 000 simultaneous clients sounds like a lot so you'll be using some form of clustering anyways

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030120/java-default-stack-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Virtual threads** were finalized in JDK 21. They are described in [JEP 444](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444), which says:

> Virtual threads are lightweight threads that dramatically reduce the effort of writing, maintaining, and observing high-throughput concurrent applications.

The model is a lot like Erlang's lightweight processes:

- Virtual threads are lightweight, quick to create and start.
- Their stacks are heap-allocated, start out small, and grow dynamically.
- A single process can have tens of thousands of them.
- There's a userspace scheduler that assigns OS threads to execute virtual threads.
- If you write code that appears to do a blocking `write` to a socket, on a virtual thread that code will actually do an asynchronous write, then yield, freeing the underlying OS thread to work on something else. The virtual thread won't be scheduled again until the write finishes.

There are also some differences from Erlang:

- `java.lang.Thread`'s public constructors still create platform threads, which run directly on new native OS threads.
- Java doesn't create a tiny, independent GC heap for each virtual thread. On the one hand, this rules out some neat GC performance tricks Erlang has; but for Java, it means virtual threads can access and modify shared data by going through locks, as Java programmers naturally expect.
- Java doesn't have Erlang's message-passing primitives (mailboxes and PIDs). It has its own primitives for inter-thread communication.
- Virtual threads in Java don't have Erlang-style error handling. Java doesn't have Erlang's process links, monitors, and [supervisors](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html). Instead, Java programs manage virtual threads using `java.lang.Thread` and executors, just like OS threads.

Answer (score 10):

There is a proposal for lightweight threads ("fibers") on the JVM called Project Loom: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html

It's in its early stages, nothing released yet, but still something to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of any "lightweight" solutions that would be on their way into the Java community process. See the [jep](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0) entries ... no word about anything like that there. There was a request for [coroutines](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029988) years back; but that thing looks pretty much "dead".

I think the closest that you can get **today** would be more something like what the [akka](http://akka.io/) framework provides to you; as those Akka actors all run with a ""lightweight thread" of activity so to speak.

Comment: In the beginning of Java, we had "green threads" which was a pure JVM implementation of threads but that was later replaced by kernel threads.

Comment: True, I vaguely remember seeing a lot of trouble with those thingies back then. But I *guess* those green threads weren't "lightweight" either ;-) ... but given your other comment, I think that Akka could be a good start for you.

Comment: Here's a quite insightful discussion about green vs native threads: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120384/why-not-green-threads

Comment: Also "green threads" or "lightweight threads" would *de facto* be M:N scheduling.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#M:N_.28hybrid_threading.29  That's pretty much died out as a viable OS scheduling model for the reasons listed.

Comment: Virtual threads JEP looks like it https://openjdk.org/jeps/436