# How to resolve 'Error occurred during initialization of VM' java?

Tags: java, jvm

I've connected to a linux-based server using ssh. Recently, I've installed JDK using following command:

`sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel`

And jdk installed successfully, but whenever I run command `java` or `javac` I get following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Even, running command `java -version`, will bring that error. When I try to give java more space using `java -Xmx512m -Xms256m -version`, I'll get following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** java: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007fc84400e270 ***
*** glibc detected *** java: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fc8440089f0 ***
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try 'which java' to see which java is running? probably it's not running to the right ones? or directly execute java from its bin directory?

Comment: Do you have set limits on memory? What kind of linux? RHEL, Fedora? run `$uname -a` and add output to the question. and `$ulimit -a` also will be helpful

Comment: I'm worried about that glibc message...

Comment: Try running it as root, if you can then check your ulimit, you may need to increase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen this sort of exception, so it is my best guess: did you try to limit [stack size by using -Xss JVM parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967885/jvm-option-xss-what-does-it-do-exactly) (i.e. -Xms8m -Xmx16m -Xss4m)? Also quick googling suggest that `export MALLOC_CHECK_=0` could possibly let you get over, but I am not sure if JVM will function well.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual Linux server?
What do you get when run:

java -Xmx1m -version

and

ulimit -a

Looks like a memory allocating problem. You can try to increase swap space if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like there is not enough memory to run the virtual machine (maybe physical memory, virtual memory or ulimit) - you should try decreasing the memory allocated to the VM (I think the default in 64Mb) and not increasing it.

Comment: java -Xmx3000m -Xms3000m
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Even larger values crash the VM

Answer (score 0):

Lower your -Xms   (not xmx).Use -Xms40m for example.If it starts as it is stated in other answers, you may be too low on memory to reclaim 256m for the vm at start.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using *JDK 32-bit version*. If so, you cannnot assign a Heap size more than `1.2GB` or something.

Either use a 64 bit JDK or try with `1.2G` as the max heap size.

Comment: But I'm not using more than 1.2GB heap, I've used -Xmx512m which means use 512MB heap at max.