# Race condition in Slick Code

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have written this slick DAO and its unit test in specs2.

My code has race conditions. When I run the same tests, I get different outputs.

The race conditions exist even though in both the functions I do Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)

DAO

```
package com.example
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import slick.jdbc.meta._
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class Person(id: Int, firstname: String, lastname: String)

class People(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "PEOPLE") {
  def id = column[Int]("PERSON_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def firstname = column[String]("PERSON_FIRST_NAME")
  def lastname = column[String]("PERSON_LAST_NAME")
  def * = (id, firstname, lastname) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply _)
}

object PersonDAO {

  private def createList(numRows: Int) : List[Person] = {
    def recFunc(counter: Int, result: List[Person]) : List[Person] = {
      counter match {
        case x if x <= numRows => recFunc(counter + 1, Person(counter, "test" + counter, "user" + counter) :: result)
        case _ => result
      }
    }
    recFunc(1, List[Person]())
  }

  val db = Database.forConfig("test1")
  val people = TableQuery[People]

  def createAndPopulate(numRows: Int) = {
    val action1 = people.schema.create
    val action2 = people ++= Seq(createList(numRows) : _* )
    val combined = db.run(action1 andThen action2)

    val future1 = combined.map { result =>
      result map {x => 
        println(s"number of rows inserted $x")
        x
      }
    }
    Await.result(future1, Duration.Inf).getOrElse(0)
  }

  def printAll() = {
    val a = people.result
    val b = db.run(a)
    val y = b map { result => 
      result map {x => x}
    }
    val z = Await.result(y, Duration.Inf)
    println(z)
    println(z.length)
    z
  }
}
```

Unit Test

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import com.example._

class HelloSpec extends Specification {
  "This usecase " should {
    "should insert rows " in {
      val x = PersonDAO.createAndPopulate(100)
      x === 100
    }
  }

  "This usecase " should {
    "return 100 rows" in {
      val x = PersonDAO.printAll()
      val y = PersonDAO.printAll()      
      y.length === 100
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this same code using `activator test` I see 2 different types of outputs on different runs

1. sometimes the code gets exception

   number of rows inserted 100
   [info] HelloSpec
   [info] 
   [info] This usecase  should
   [info] + should insert rows 
   [info] 
   [info] This usecase should
   [info] ! return 100 rows 
   [error]    JdbcSQLException: : Table PEOPLE not found; SQL statement:
   [error] select x2."PERSON_ID", x2."PERSON_FIRST_NAME", x2."PERSON_LAST_NAME" from "PEOPLE" x2 [42S02-60]  (Message.java:84)
   [error] org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:84)
   [error] org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:88)
   [error] org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:66)
2. Sometimes the 1st function call returns 0 rows and the 2nd function call returns 100 values

   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
   number of rows inserted 100
   Vector()
   0
   Vector(Person(100,test100,user100), Person(99,test99,user99), Person(98,test98,user98), Person(97,test97,user97), Person(96,test96,user96), Person(95,test95,user95), Person(94,test94,user94), Person(93,test93,user93), Person(92,test92,user92), Person(91,test91,user91), Person(90,test90,user90), Person(89,test89,user89), Person(88,test88,user88), Person(87,test87,user87), Person

I don't understand why does my code have these race conditions because I block on future in each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that two test cases should run serial, one after the other is not right. The test cases are running parallel. Just use [sequential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458194) to verify that thats the case.