# How to predict the maximum call depth of a recursive method?

Tags: java, memory, recursion, jvm, stack-overflow

For the purposes of estimating the maximum call depth a recursive method may achieve with a given amount of memory, what is the (approximate) formula for calculating the memory used before a stack overflow error is likely to occur?

#### Edit:

Many have responded with "it depends", which is reasonable, so let's remove some of the variables by using a trivial but concrete example:

```
public static int sumOneToN(int n) {
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n + sumOneToN(n - 1);
}
```

It is easy to show that running this in my Eclipse IDE explodes for `n` just under 1000 (surprisingly low to me).
Could this call depth limit have been estimated without executing it?

Edit: I can't help thinking that Eclipse has a fixed max call depth of 1000, because I got to `998`, but there's one for the main, and one for the initial call to the method, making `1000` in all. This is "too round" a number IMHO to be a coincidence. I'll investigate further. I have just Dux overhead the -Xss vm parameter; it's the maximum stack size, so Eclipse runner must have `-Xss1000` set somewhere

Comment: (It seems like this would depend on the JVM and possibly architecture.)

Comment: I _guess_ it's just the local variables + frame pointer + return address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734108/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-the-java-call-stack

Comment: I also think it's impossible to estimate without measuring

Comment: @JanDvorak + the size of the objects created

Comment: @SJuan76 What kind of objects do you mean?

Comment: Recursion really has nothing to do with this (except it's the most common way to generate a really deep call stack). For the purposes of determining call depth limit, recursive calls are no different than any other type of call. (Of course, a compiler might eliminate tail recursion, in which case recursion is an active distraction from your question.)

Comment: Any. `List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();` will use up more memory than `List<String> a;`. The OP asks for total memory usage.

Comment: @SJuan76 The OP, IIUC, asks for stack usage only.

Comment: @JanDvorak Does Java have a separate memory space for stack and heap? I really do not know, if it is yes then object creation is irrelevant for recursion (at least until it runs of space itself), if not they both count.

Comment: @SJuan76 there are two different exceptions, `OutOfMemoryError` and `StackOverflowError`, so I'm assuming Java has the notion of a stack size / heap size :-)

Comment: Java certainly has separate stack and heap spaces, but as referenced in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13995940/839646), stack size may be variable and/or dynamic, and stack frames may be allocated on the heap, so all of this depends on the JVM in use and how it's configured.

Comment: @RyanStewart Is it possible that the possibility of stack = heap is intended primarily for devices that don't have a separate stack memory, never to be used on x86/x64?

Comment: @Jan: Anything's possible :) I haven't found anything on google indicating how any real JVMs behave in this area, so it may be that this feature just isn't used. I suppose in the end, regardless of where things are allocated, you'll be bounded by the overall system memory available, but you can't really derive a formula from that, as the OP asked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is clearly JVM- and possibly also architecture-specific.

I've measured the following:

```
  static int i = 0;
  public static void rec0() {
      i++;
      rec0();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ...
      try {
          i = 0; rec0();
      } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
          System.out.println(i);
      }
      ...
  }
```

using

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

running on x86.

With a 20MB Java stack (`-Xss20m`), the amortized cost fluctuated around 16-17 bytes per call. The lowest I've seen was 16.15 bytes/frame. I therefore conclude that the cost is 16 bytes and the rest is other (fixed) overhead.

A function that takes a single `int` has basically the same cost, 16 bytes/frame.

Interestingly, a function that takes ten `ints` requires 32 bytes/frame. I am not sure why the cost is so low.

The above results apply after the code's been JIT compiled. Prior to compilation the per-frame cost is *much, much* higher. I haven't yet figured out a way to estimate it reliably. **However, this does mean that you have no hope of reliably predicting maximum recursion depth until you can reliably predict whether the recursive function has been JIT compiled.**

All of this was tested with a `ulimit` stack sizes of 128K and 8MB. The results were the same in both cases.

Comment: How are you measuring the recursion depth?

Comment: He/She can easily measure the recursive depth with a static member field that is incremented on each call

Comment: About 16 bytes per stack frame on a 64-bit system looks like a return address + one extra address (frame pointer? `this` pointer (which is technically `null`, not absent)?)

Comment: @Bohemian: I've expanded the answer (didn't have time to do it last night).

Comment: @JanDvorak: I would expect there to be no `this` at all. I can only guess what the second 8 bytes are for. Could well be a pointer of some sort.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a way to make HotSpot print out the assembly it produces when JIT compiling? That would answer a lot of these questions...

Comment: @NPE You could try a classic disassembler like CheatEngine. Not sure how to find the compiled piece of code then, though. I will try to, though.

Answer (score 10):

Only a partial answer: from [JVM Spec 7, 2.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2), stack frames can be allocated on the heap, and the stack size may be dynamic. I couldn't say for certain, but it seems it should be possible to have your stack size bounded only by your heap size:

> Because the Java virtual machine stack is never manipulated directly except to push and pop frames, frames may be heap allocated.

and

> This specification permits Java virtual machine stacks either to be of
>   a fixed size or to dynamically expand and contract as required by the
>   computation. If the Java virtual machine stacks are of a fixed size,
>   the size of each Java virtual machine stack may be chosen
>   independently when that stack is created.
>
> A Java virtual machine implementation may provide the programmer or
>   the user control over the initial size of Java virtual machine stacks,
>   as well as, in the case of dynamically expanding or contracting Java
>   virtual machine stacks, control over the maximum and minimum sizes.

So it'll be up to the JVM implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Addig to NPEs answer:

The maximum stack depth seems to be *flexible*. The following test program prints **vastly** different numbers:

```
public class StackDepthTest {
    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
            testInstance();
        }
    }

    public static void testInstance() {
        StackDepthTest sdt = new StackDepthTest();
        try {
            i=0;
            sdt.instanceCall();
        } catch(StackOverflowError e){}
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void instanceCall(){
        ++i;
        instanceCall();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
10825
10825
59538
59538
59538
59538
59538
59538
59538
59538
```

I've used the default of this JRE:

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

So the conclusion is: If you pus had enough (i.e. more than twice) you get a second chance ;-)

Comment: Really interesting but I'm not completely sure I'd trust my VM after catching a StackOverflow...  I guess it would be safe but it's still a little scary.

Comment: The whole question is about stuff on the edge. My hope is that someone can shed some light on the condition when the JVM switches the gears (from 10k to 60k).

Comment: If you change the -Xss setting, it changes how many times you get the "low" vs the "high" output. My guess would be that the JVM just gets into a corrupted state, which is why you don't try to recover from Errors.

Comment: @RyanStewart: OR (already mentioned in some other answer): The JIT compiler kicks in and uses a second, more compact stack frame format. Also I don't believe, that the JVM is in a corrupt state since this way out of the JVM sandbox would be just to easy. And after all the error is detected by the JVM.

Comment: @A.H. I agree. It's the compiler. I changed your code to run ten times but cut off at about 10k recursions, thereby avoiding the overflow. Then after that ran one more time until overflow, and it had bumped up to the ~60k.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, it all depends.

First of all, the Java Stack size can be changed.

Second of all, the stack frame size of a given method can vary based on different variables. You can look at the Call Stack Frame Size section of [Call stack - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_frame_sizes) for more details.

Comment: Stack frames may be heap-allocated, so frame size may be irrelevant, depending.

Answer (score 2):

depends on your system-architecture (32 or 64 bit addresses), the amount of local variables and parameters of the method.
If it is  [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) no overhead, if the compiler optimize it to a loop.

You see, no simple answer.

Comment: This is tagged "java", so we're assuming we're talking about a JVM here.

Comment: @RyanStewart There are 32 and 64bit JVMs

Comment: There are, but memory in the JVM works the same regardless. There also is no tail recursion in the JVM, nor do I know of any java compiler that will do any such optimization. Therefore, it seemed to me you must be talking about something else.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: I just made a google search and was shocked that there is no tail recursion optimization for java yet. But might be in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the empirical road and experiment with your code and the `-Xss` setting. See here for more: [JVM option -Xss - What does it do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967885/jvm-option-xss-what-does-it-do-exactly)