# Print reverse in linkedlist

Tags: java, printing, linked-list, reverse

I want to write function Print Reverse of LinkedList in Java. I write like this but it doesn't work. Compiler warn that `NullPointerException`.

```
void ReversePrint(Node head) {
    int[] array = null;
    int i = 0;
    Node tmp;
    for (tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next) {
        array[i] = tmp.data;
        i++;
    }
    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--){
        System.out.println(array[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code, `array` is not initialized, it is `null` .

Comment: But I try to fix by int[] array ={0};

Comment: And it's not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you need int[] array = new int[ size of the list ];

Comment: Also, `for (int j = i....` will give you an index exception. You want `j = i - 1`.

Comment: For future questions it would be best if you also **post the complete error message** here. Especially the `StackTrace` contains information which is helpful for debugging. It exactly tells us at which line the `NPE` occurred and which events triggered that, then we don't need to find the source first.

Answer (score 2):

You get the `NullPointerException` because the variable `array` is `null`:

```
int[] array = null;
```

You need to initialize it first with a value before you are using it here:

```
array[i] = tmp.data;
```

For example with a statement like this:

```
int[] array = new int[size];
```

Where `size` should probably be the size of your `LinkedList`. If you, for whatever reason, don't know the size, you can use the class `ArrayList` which realizes arrays with *dynamic size* (it guesses a size and if your exceeding it, it will re-allocate a bigger array and copy everything over and so on).

Here's a version using said `ArrayList`:

```
// Method names should start with a lower-case letter
void reversePrint(Node head) {
    // Initialize an empty ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    Node tmp;
    for (tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next) {
        // Set the element at position i of the ArrayList
        dataList.set(i, tmp.data);
        i++;
    }

    // See next comment
    i--;

    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--){
        // Get the element at position j of ArrayList and print it
        System.out.println(dataList.get(j));
    }
}
```

---

Note that you will also encounter an `IndexOutOfBoundException` since your `i` is `1` to big when reaching the print-loop. This is because you increased it also in the last iteration of your first loop:

```
// Suppose last iteration, i is (list.size() - 1) then
for (tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next) {
    array[i] = tmp.data;
    // i is now list.size()
    i++;
}
```

You need one `i--` between the loops or `int j = i - 1` in your loop initialization.

---

If you are realizing a **doubly-linked** list instead of only a **single-linked** list then note that you do not need to story values in an array first. You then can directly print the values by starting at `tail` and following `tmp.prev` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with a recursive method:

```
void ReversePrint(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        ReversePrint(node.next);
        System.out.println(node.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple yes. But depending on the size of the list that may easily end up in `StackOverflowError`. Just as a note for OP.

Comment: so I shouldn't use this code if the size of the list is big, right @Zabuza

Comment: That is correct. This recursion calls `size`-often the method before it starts to finish one of them. Every method-call costs some space on the **stack** (you need to remember variables, pointers, everything from all other method calls). At some point the limit is reached and you'll get a `StackOverflowError`: [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror) and [How many recursive calls before StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285115/how-many-recursive-calls-before-stackoverflowerror)