# When does StackOverflowError occur?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, stack-overflow

According to Oracle, a [StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) is:

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

I know what recursion is and normally recursive functions, if not terminated properly, lead to StackOverflowError. To check the number of recursive calls that happen before `StackOverflowError` is thrown, I wrote this code:

```
package ErrorCases;

public class StackOverFlowError {
static int i=0;
void a()
{

    //System.out.println("called "+(++i));
    try{
        ++i;
    a();
    }catch(Error e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

       new StackOverFlowError().a();

   }

}
```

the value of `i` gives the count of recursive calls to `a()` before JVM threw StackOverflowError.
The value of `i` is different in every run like:

```
output 1: class java.lang.StackOverflowError
           10466
Output 2: class java.lang.StackOverflowError
           10470
```

**My query is ?**

1. How deep the recursion has to happen before JVM throws
   `StackOverflowError`?
2. Can we recover once a `StackOverflowError` has
       been thrown?

Comment: Recovery from Stack Overflow requires total abstinence -- oops, I mean is pretty iffy.  If the code was engaged in some complex operation at the time there may not be enough stack space to allow it to back out.  And a lot of in-progress operations may not protect against such a failure and will fail to back out/reset at all.

Comment: best question i read in a long time. made me think! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The depth depends on two things:

1: The size of the stack.

2: The amount of stack space used in each recursion.

Function parameters, local variables and the return address are all allocated on the stack while objects are allocated on the heap.

**Recovery**

It is possible to recover.

```
try {
    myDeepRecursion();
} catch (StackOverflowError e) {
  // We are back from deep recursion. Stack should be ok again.
}
```

However, note the following regarding errors (from the java API doc):

`An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.`

**EDIT:**

A note of caution: While catching exceptions inside a recursive function is ok, don't try to catch errors. If the stack is full, then the error handling will cause new errors. Simple things, such as a call to `System.out.println()` will fail because there is no room left on the stack for the return address.

That is why errors should be caught outside the recursive function.

Comment: Can we control the depth?

Comment: You can use the jvm option -Xss like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967885/jvm-option-xss-what-does-it-do-exactly)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-to-java-stack-size

Comment: Not from the outside. There is no "maxRecursionDepth" parameter to give the JVM. You can, however, specify the stack size with the `-Xss` JVM parameter.

Comment: Added an edit in my answer.

Comment: But the code is working properly. Even i am able to call function `b()` form inside the `catch`

Comment: What do you mean with properly?  It will recurse down until it fails, then it will fail again in the error handler of the lowest recursion, then return up one level to the error handler of the second lowest recursion. There it will recurse down into `b` until it runs out of stack space. That error is caught in the third lowest recursion of `a` where it will again recurse down into `b` and so on, 10000+ times until it is all the way back up.

Answer (score 3):

> How deep the recursion has to happen before JVM throws StackOverflowError?

It really depends on the machine you're working with and your JVM and its configuration. (it's 6000 - 8500 on my current setup with a lot of tasks in the background) and at most, the this you do in the application and the recursive method.

> Can we recover once a StackOverflowError has been thrown?

No! I Java throws an error, there is no way back to normal. That is the main difference between Exceptions and Errors.

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch

[Read more about Errors here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)

[Read more about Java stack size myths here](http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=411)

**Edit:**

You can still do things after an error occurs, but does it make sense? You have a serious error in your code! You can't be sure that everything works correctly!

Your code is not terminating because you call the method again which is the same like an endless loop

Comment: They why the output shows different values every time i run it ? I am running on the same machine

Comment: basicly yes. a computer is a working machine and has more or less stuff to do

Comment: in the `catch(Error e), ` call other functions, If stack is full, how it is working?

Comment: Please check the second code . Its not terminating. How it id getting stack to print ?

Comment: it prints the stack, because the programm is still running (in an unstable condition). it is not terminating because calling b() in b() is an endless loop ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you may see different stack depths is that the stack frames are not necessarily the same size. The Hotspot JVM for example has different stack frames for JIT compiled code and for interpreted code. The JIT compiler works in parallel with the running code, so external factors like load on the machine may have an effect on when / if the JVM starts using JIT stack frames.

One thing that you should keep in mind is the fact that when you get a `StackOverflowError`, almost anything that you do may cause another `StackOverflowError`. For example printing the name of the error class in the `catch` part may also run out of stack space, so another `StackOverflowError` will be thrown down the stack.

Some people claim that you cannot recover from an `Error` because the JVM is shutting down. That is not correct; you can recover from some errors. What's tricky about `StackOverflowError` and `OutOfMemoryError` is that once you catch one you have absolutely no guarantees of the state of the program; for example a key data structure you use might be in an inconsistent state. This makes recovery hard or impossible in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if `StackOverflowError` means "no stack left"? why am i able to call function `b()` from inside the `catch()`?

Comment: When the error is thrown, the topmost frame is removed from the stack and the error is handled by the `catch` block in the calling method. If there's not enough stack space another `StackOverflowError` is thrown and another frame is removed. This process continues until so many frames have been removed that the catch block can complete without an error being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters and local variables are allocated on the stack (with reference types the object lives on the heap and a variable references that object). The stack typically lives at the upper end of your address space and as it is used up it heads towards the bottom of the address space (ie towards zero).

Your process also has a heap, which lives at the bottom end of your process. As you allocate memory this heap can grow towards the upper end of your address space. As you can see, there is the potential for the heap to "collide" with the stack (a bit like techtonic plates!!!).
[[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

So the StackOIverflowError will depend on your stack size as well as your heap size which will depend from execution to execution because of lot of factors like GC.

Also as the name says it is Error and not Exception. There is no recovery from it. JVM will shut down.

Comment: Thanks, But if the JVM shuts down, then how can we `catch` it and run code ?

Comment: The JVM will only shut down if the Error is not caught.

Comment: That is same for the `Exception` too, then.In that sense, `Exception` if not handled, will cause JVM crash.

Comment: But catched Exceptions are supposed to be handled, uncatched Exceptions in some case where as Errors in no case at all.

Comment: If you catch a Throwable before it "bubbles out" all the way, it will not take down the JVM.  If you do not catch it, it will.  This is true for all Throwables, be they Exceptions or Errors.  The difference is in what one is *supposed to do* with them, which always needs to be taken with a grain of salt.