# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to run a test from jmeter using "webdriver sampler" with 1500 users with a ramp-up 60 sec in one hour...
everything is going well, but at one point, for example, 15 minutes later... I get this error

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to allocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to unguard stack red zone failed.
An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x000000006671bbfb, pid=12248, tid=0x0000000000000358
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_341-b10) (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.341-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x20bbfb]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Call to MiniDumpWriteDump() failed (Error 0x800705af: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\workspace\test\hs_err_pid12248.log
errorlevel=-1073741819
Press any key to continue . . . 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I use chromedriver headless

This is the command line that I use in jenkins

`apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/jmeter.bat -n -t "test.jmx"`

jmeter version 5.5

what is the problem and possible cause

also i get this message sometimes in the output

```
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.5.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Answer (score 0):

> An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred

it means that either you have an endless [loop](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-for-loop) somewhere or create a large object which exceeds the [thread stack size](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap)

The solutions are in:

- inspect your code for any loop instances (for, foreach, while) which may fail to exit
- increase stack size by passing the relevant [`-Xss` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967885/jvm-option-xss-what-does-it-do-exactly)
- allocate another machine and switch to [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter) mode with 750 users per machine

In general [using Selenium for performance testing is not recommended](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/), it might be a better idea to conduct the main load using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and use 1-2 threads in another Thread Group running WebDriver Samplers to measure frontend performance, rendering speed, scripts execution time, collecting web vitals metrics and so on.